# issue with creating perl script to imitate linux command "ifconfig"

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, ifconfig

I have an assignment in which I am to create a Perl script in Linux to imitate the command `ifconfig`. This command basically shows you information about your network interfaces. I have already created the program, but a few lines are giving me some issues, I would appreciate if anyone could correct the code for me. The errors I am getting says that `$get_iface_data requires an explicit package name at line 8`, however I do not know how to declare that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Int::Stats;
use Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper;

my $Iface   = $ARGV[0];
my $rx_packets  = $get_Iface_data->value($Iface, 'rx_packets');
my $Iface_Info = Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper::Ifconfig('list', '', '', '');
print "\tether ". $Iface_Info->{$Iface}{'ether'}."\n";
```

My assignment basically requires me to get an interface as input, and display the info about that interface, as the `ifconfig` command would do. I also used two packages, `Net::Int::Stats` and `Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper`. The only difference between my script and the `ifconfig` command is my script will require an interface  as parameter

Comment: First of all you should tell us what error message you get. You do not even use `$get_Iface_data` and I guess you can not call any method on it. Strings are no objects in Perl but a string is what you get from `STDIN`.

Comment: I have added the error i got, and corrected my code

Answer (score 1):

Well, where do you defined `$get_Iface_data`?

The `$foo->bar` is a method call syntax. This means that `$foo` is some sort of *object* and `bar` is a method that can be used on that object.

Do you understand Object Oriented Programming and how Perl uses it? Perl has an excellent [tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) to help you get started.

What it comes done to is that you can't use a particular method (think subroutine) except on an object of that class. From this snippet of code, and what your error states, you never defined `$get_Iface_data`, so you have to define it. In this case, you have to *create* the object:

```
my $get_Iface_data = Net::Int::Stats->new();
```

Now, you can use the various `Net::Int::Stats` *methods* on the `%get_Iface_data` object:

```
my $rx_packets  = $get_Iface_data->value($Iface, 'rx_packets');
```

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $int in regexp compilation at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Net/Int/Stats.pm line 113.
Use of uninitialized value $int in hash element at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Net/Int/Stats.pm line 157.
Use of uninitialized value $Iface in hash element at ./test2.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test2.pl line 11.
 ether

Comment: @user218001 when you ran the script, did you pass an interface in the command line, i.e. `perl test2.pl eth0`?

Comment: @user218001 - You got _Use of uninitialized value $Iface in hash element at ./test2.pl line 11_. Where is `$Iface` getting it's value? See that `my $Iface = $ARGV[0]`? Are you passing the interface name into the program when you run it? As imran already commented?

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the line where you create the Net::Int::Stats object:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Int::Stats;
use Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper;

my $Iface   = $ARGV[0];
my $get_Iface_data = Net::Int::Stats->new();
my $rx_packets  = $get_Iface_data->value($Iface, 'rx_packets');
my $Iface_Info = Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper::Ifconfig('list', '', '', '');
print "\tether ". $Iface_Info->{$Iface}{'ether'}."\n";
```